# Array types are now written with the brackets around the element type?

Tags: ios, arrays, dictionary, swift

i'm trying to declare an array of dictionary.

```
var dataSource: Dictionary<String, String>[][] = [[], []]
```

But the Xcode appears "Array types are not written withe the brackets around the element type?"

and I have a protocol in another file, as below

```
protocol CreateTaskDelegate {
func taskCreated(task:Dictionary<String, String>)
}
```

How can I figure that out?
Thanks.

Comment: I can't quite see what your protocol has to do with your declaration. Also, bear in mind that you're misquoting the error message and giving it completely the opposite meaning: array types are **now** written with the brackets around the element type. If you don't just want to instantiate an array of dictionaries of String to String type—which would be `var dataSource: [Dictionary<String, String>] = []
`—it might help to try to describe what you want better.

Answer (score 0):

```
var dataSource = [[String:String]]()
```

i guess you are looking for this?

```
var dataSource = [Dictionary<String, String>]()
```

its equivalent... they both (as well as your protocol) have the type `[[String:String]]`

Comment: Thanks. But in my case, I have a protocol in another file.             protocol CreateTaskDelegate {
        func taskCreated(task:Dictionary<String, String>)
    }